# ArcReader project and GDB Protected. How to read on ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, arcreader

I have a project that can only be viewed in ArcReader93, the project format is pmf. When I open it it asks for a password (which I know),
[image: I open the project and enter the password]

once I load the project I can consult the information, change colors of the layers among others, and generate a "map" (it's awful) to print.

[image: 1- Panel layers, with properties to change colors, but not for export. 2- Folders with project data]

However I need to load the database in ArcGIS to perform geoprocessing with the information, but when trying to open the GDB with ArcGIS is not possible, only error appears. It does not request the password.

The folders are:

```
data: contains file00.gdb and file01.gdb
Pmf: contains project.pmf
```

The worst thing is that it can only be opened in ArcReader93, When trying to open the GDB in ArcGIS , it does not recognize it as a geodatabase But the option to enter the password never appears .Is there any way to export the information from the GDB or at least access it from ArcGIS , or Qgis?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Answer (score 2):

To access the data for geoprocessing, you will either need the original dataset that the PMF/gdb were created from, or a copy of the PMF geodatabase data package that is **not locked**.

As far as I'm aware you cannot open a protected PMF or its GDB files unless the PMF explicitly allows it.  When the PMF and GDB is created there are options for when and how things are opened, so if those weren't set to allow it, then you can't do it.

It's the PMF that is password protected, which is why you don't get a prompt for password when trying to access the GDB contents from ArcGIS.

[image]

The GDB files will be locked/compressed and only able to be accessed by that PMF.  These are both options that can be enabled/disabled when *creating* the PMF, but not bypassed once they are set in the document.

[image]

In my ArcGIS 10.5 I am able to view the feature classes in a Compressed/Locked ArcReader geodatabase

[image]

however I cannot add these to a map - I get an Open Failed error

[image]

If I create my PMF and only Compress the GDB (not Locked) I can view *and* add these to my map

[image]

To access the data for geoprocessing, you will either need the *original* dataset that the PMF/gdb were created from, or a copy of the PMF geodatabase data package that is **not locked**.